# Replace column index with ListComprehension

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Pandas Dataframe like this

[image]

which is related to the patients and their notes about their problem. The column "Problem" contains `null` values and I want to fill this column values according to the patient's notes.

How can I do this?

I was thinking to do it in this way that if in `df["PATİENT NOTE"]` we observe "KNEE", then we can replace `None` with the word `KNEE` like this:

```
`df["PROBLEM"].replace("col,"KNEE")`
```

or if in `df["PATİENT NOTE"]` we get the word "ARM", we can use this command to replace the word:

```
`df["PROBLEM"].replace(col,"ARM")`
```

But I don't know how to do this. So, I was wondering if anybody can help me?

I would very much appreciate your help.

Comment: need text or code of example, not image. and make desired output

Answer (score 0):

You can split `PATIENT NOTE` column. Then get first string after `ON MY`:

```
df.loc[df['PROBLEM'].isnull(),"PROBLEM"] = df['PATIENT NOTE'].str.split('ON MY ').str.get(1) # This only applies to None/nan rows.
```